# Randomly clicking all the tabs for an infinite amount

Tags: python, css, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to randomly click all unopened tabs (elements) on this [page](https://www.unibet.com.au/betting#filter/football).

The below tends to work however unfortunately, using this approach it does not seem to click all the elements. I assume for some reason it does not like for index in indexes (or does not load all of them correctly). Adding `while True:`, tends to fix this, though I am unsure how to randomise for an infinite amount. Any ideas?

```
options = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="KambiBC-mod-event-group-header__event-count"]')

indexes = [index for index in range(len(options))]
shuffle(indexes)
for index in indexes:
    time.sleep(1)
    clickMe = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'(//*[@class="KambiBC-mod-event-group-header__event-count"])[%s]' % str(index + 1))))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", clickMe)
    clickMe.click()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Adding `while True:`

```
while True:
    time.sleep(0)
    #clickMe = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'(//*[@class="KambiBC-mod-event-group-header__event-count"])[%s]' % str(index + 1))))
    clickMe = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '(//*[@class="KambiBC-mod-event-group-header__event-count"])[%s]' % str(index + 1))))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", clickMe)
    clickMe.click()
    time.sleep(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all options appears simultaneously, but they added by groups one after another.

You need to wait until all options are available.

Try below code:

```
def get_options_length():
    list_length = len(wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="KambiBC-collapsible-header KambiBC-mod-event-group-header"]'))))
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        if list_length == len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="KambiBC-collapsible-header KambiBC-mod-event-group-header"]')):
            break
        else:
            list_length = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="KambiBC-collapsible-header KambiBC-mod-event-group-header"]'))
    return list_length

indexes = [index for index in range(get_options_length())]
shuffle(indexes)
for index in indexes:
    time.sleep(1)
    clickMe = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'(//*[@class="KambiBC-collapsible-header KambiBC-mod-event-group-header"])[%s]' % str(index + 1))))
    clickMe = clickMe.find_element_by_xpath('.//span')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", clickMe)
    clickMe.click()
```

Comment: I seem to get:     indexes = [index for index in range(get_options_length)]
TypeError: 'function' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: Oh, sorry :) `indexes = [index for index in range(get_options_length())]`

Comment: That fixed that error though I am getting instead now:  File "C:/Users/Bain3/PycharmProjects/untitled4/11The unibet.py", line 1311, in <module>
    indexes = [index for index in range(get_options_length())]
  File "C:/Users/Bain3/PycharmProjects/untitled4/11The unibet.py", line 1302, in get_options_length
    list_length = len(wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="KambiBC-mod-event-group-header__event-count"]'))))
TypeError: until() missing 1 required positional argument: 'method'

Comment: Awesome.  So it clicks some of them then it tends to pop up with Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Bain3/PycharmProjects/untitled4/11The unibet.py", line 1315, in <module>
    clickMe = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'(//*[@class="KambiBC-mod-event-group-header__event-count"])[%s]' % str(index + 1))))
  File "C:\Users\Bain3\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Thats because after each click the number of elements decreased by one: the element that receives the click is changed and cannot be found by `'//*[@class="KambiBC-mod-event-group-header__event-count"]'` selector anymore... Check updated